# How we can trust user info from Apple sign-in when it is not included in id_token which integrity can be verified by Apple's public key

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, apple-sign-in

In accepted response here https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/118209 is written `To request user information in the id_token...` But it is not true, user info is never in id_token but as standalnoe unsigned "user" parameter and just after first sign-in (Ok, Apple decided just one time and makes developer life complicated as Apple always does) after redirection from https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize to redirect_uri When authorizing we set also 'response_type' => 'code id_token' + 'scope' => 'name email' but user info is not included in decoded id_token but just as separate parameter "user"...

```
  POST params Array
  (
    [state] => ...
    [code] => ...
    [id_token] => eyJr...UUg
    [user] => {"name":{"firstName":"...","lastName":"..."},"email":"..."}
  )
```

What about security? How we can trust fields in user param? Email, OK, it is included also in id_token which can we verify by signature and Appples public key. User can stop request (e.g. turns internet off), can modify "user" post field in request and sends it to developer.

I tried to request https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token with provided "code" param but user info is not available. Response can be trusted but user info not available. Not available directly as "user" param and also not available again in id_token.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be some [open issues](https://www.google.com/amp/s/hub.packtpub.com/openid-foundation-questions-apples-sign-in-feature-says-it-has-security-and-privacy-risks/amp/) with Apple's implementation, as you indicate.

A potential reliability problem is how Apple return name and email details only the first time. If the app experiences an issue saving this data, then by default the data is never received again and you cannot recover.

I would deal with this via some kind of custom registration or welcome screen that prompts new users for personal information. This might include other information you need to store in your identity data, but which does not exist in Apple, eg a country. You could also use this to ignore any `user` data from Apple that you cannot verify.

**AUTHORIZATION SERVER**

Ideally I would also recommend using an authorization server to manage the connection to Apple. The user account data and any custom screens could then be stored / managed there, and you would not need to deal with provider specific behaviour in your application code.

Your apps would then use only standard OpenID Connect, and you would have the potential to authenticate users in many other ways, in addition to Apple. That's the idea with OAuth: changing the way authentication works should require zero code changes to your apps.